# Transpose rows and columns in data frame using first column entries as colnames in new R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row

My data frame df looks like this:

```
      ID     A   B   C    D...Z
1   name1    4   6   7    8...
2   name2    5   8   3    5...
...
50 name50    4   6   7    8...
```

This is what I need:

```
   ID   name1   name2 ...name50 
1  A      4      5    ...  4
2  B      6      8    ...  6
etc.
```

I have tried the transpose command, `as.data.frame(t(df))`, but the index number for the rows (1,2,...50) becomes the column names, which I do not want.
I would like to use the first column in the old data frame (`name1`, `name2`, ...) to become the column names of the new data frame.
I also lose the index numbers for the rows, which I need.

Main problem is that `df` has about 15k rows, and 45 columns, so swapping rows and columns using brute force, is not that simple.

Yes, I need the data in a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  rownames_to_column("value") %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1,]) %>%
  .[-1,] %>%
  `rownames<-`(NULL)
```

Output is:

```
  ID name1 name2 name50
1  A     4     5      4
2  B     6     8      6
3  C     7     3      7
4  D     8     5      8
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("name1", "name2", "name50"), A = c(4L, 
5L, 4L), B = c(6L, 8L, 6L), C = c(7L, 3L, 7L), D = c(8L, 5L, 
8L)), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Set row names to the ID column values first and then transpose:

```
> df
      ID A B C D
1  name1 4 6 7 8
2  name2 5 8 3 5
3 name50 4 6 7 8

> rownames(df)<-df$ID

> df$ID<-NULL

> df
       A B C D
name1  4 6 7 8
name2  5 8 3 5
name50 4 6 7 8

> t(df)
  name1 name2 name50
A     4     5      4
B     6     8      6
C     7     3      7
D     8     5      8
```

Comment: Noticed that row columns from old data frame became row names for new one, but i still needed the standard index numbers for the rows. Had to add rownames as a new column in data frame, and then rename rownames using rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df). Will add your suggestion to bag of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drop the row numbers, do the transpose as you were before, and then add the row numbers back in with: `row.names(df) <-  1 : nrow(df)`.

Comment: I combined the suggestion above with yours to provide another solution to my problem.